# Change user-agent for Selenium web-driver without closing the browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, user-agent

I have the following code in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "whatever")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

I'm trying to change the user-agent when i open new tab without closing the browser each time, Is there anyway?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: @cruisepandey i can't change user-agent without close the browser. i'm trying to find way  to change user-agent without close the browser. the code above let me change user-agent just when i close the browser and open it agin with selenium.